# jQuery - add button style when loaded and remove the style when others are clicked.

Tags: jquery, css

I am wanting to add style attribute to a certain button menu when the page is loaded and remove that style and add to the button that is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadJC();
});

function loadJC() {
    $('#jcMenu').attr('style', 'background-color:#29ABE2;');
}

$('.menu').click(function () {
    if ($(this) !== $('#jcMenu')) {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:#29ABE2;');
        $('#jcMenu').removeAttr().end();
    }
});
```

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/4CN7p/1/) and I am not sure
if my logic in the bottom function is appropriate with jQuery syntax.

Comment: You should use a css class, and jQuery's [``toggleClass``](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh okay, I see what you are trying to do.  My suggestion would be the following:

- create an `active` class
- add `active` class to button in HTML
- on click, remove that class from siblings.

Maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="dateMenu" class="span2 btn menu">Date</button>
    <button id="jcMenu" class="active span3 btn menu">Job Category</button>
    <button id="jpMenu" class="span2 btn menu">Job Priority</button>
    <button id="wsMenu" class="span3 btn menu">Workflow Status</button>
    <button class="span1 btn custom"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button id="refresh" class="span1 btn custom"> <i class="icon-refresh"></i></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    color:white;
    background:none;
    background-color:#B3B3B3;
    border-radius:0;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color:#29ABE2;
    color:white;
}
.custom {
    background:none;
}
.active{
    background-color:#29ABE2;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active')
                   .siblings('.menu')
                   .removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4CN7p/4/

Comment: @SeongLee Sure thing! Btw, I edited my solution so make sure to use the updated answer! Let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // load this background when dom loads
    $('#jcMenu').css('background-color', '#29ABE2');

    // when user click change the style.
    $('.menu').click(function(){
        // reset all menus to grey
        $('.menu').css('background-color', '#B3B3B3');
        // only this one that i clicked use blue background
        $(this).css('background-color', '#29ABE2');
    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems to accommodate more of my original code so this answer actually deserves my acceptance but the selected answer came available at a better timing with ideas that I could look into for improvement. I really appreciate it.